# Will a WCF web service call IDisposable.Dispose() on my object?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an object which implements the IDisposable interface.  I have a WCF web service which returns the IDisposable object.

While debugging, I see the Dispose() method of my class is being called even though I have not coded with a "using" statement or called Dispose() directly myself.

I found a book, **Programming WCF Services, by Juval Lowy**, in which he says "When the method call returns, if the object implements IDisposable, WCF calls IDisposable.Dispose() on it."

My stack trace shows a call from the following is triggering my Dispose() method.

```
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.DisposeParametersCore(Boolean excludeInput)
```

Is the WCF Service what is calling my object's Dispose() method?

Comment: If you had just put a breakpoint in your dispose method, and when it was hit you looked at the callstack window, you would have your answer.

Comment: I included my call stack in the question.  System.ServiceModel is the WCF service.  I'm just looking for validation I am not being an idiot.

Comment: A call stack is usually more than one line :/ Anyhow, I'm not prepared to decide if you're an idiot or not, so good luck :)

Comment: Well played.!!!